# Cyclic groups generators, understanding example $\mathbb{Z}_6$

Tags: group-theory

I am studying group theory but I am having hard time understanding the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n$. On the material I am studying I have the following example:

> $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0_6,1_6,...,5_6\}$ and $1_6=7_6=13_6=-5_6=...=\{...,-11,-5,1,7,13,...\}$

I know that this equality $1_6=7_6=13_6=-5_6$ holds because each of the remainder is $1$. But I do not understand what ($\mathbb{Z}_6)=\{0_6,1_6,...,5_6\}$ means.

**Question:**

**1)** Considering $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0_6,1_6,...,5_6\}$. Is $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0_6,1_6,...,5_6\}$ all the generators of $6$?

**2)** How can I generate $\mathbb{Z}_6$ from $5$? I am thinking each one of this numbers is a cycle to attain $\mathbb{Z}_6$. However if we consider $\langle 5 \rangle=5+5+5...+5$ as a cyclic subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z},+)$. How can $5_6$ generate $6$? How do I read $5_6$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Downvoting without explaining is a recognized way of conducting business here – get used to it. Anyway, it's best to interpret $a_b$ as the coset of $b{\bf Z}$ containing $a$, that is, as the set $\{\,a,a\pm b,a\pm2b,\dots\,\}$. That should dispel much of your confusion. But I don't know what you mean by "generators of 6". Numbers don't have generators – groups have generators.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is the only example I have on the material I am studying. I have not covered "cosets". So I cannot understand what you mean. I am studying Group Theory for the first time. The parameters that society follows are not necessarily the best for the reason I have pointed out. Why then should I get used to downvoting without explanation? Do not answer my last question please. I am not looking for a discussion here of this matter. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You are hoping that somebody will help you with a very elementary problem in group theory. So you are relying on the generosity and helpfulness of people whom you don't know. So in your position you should be willing to accept the conventions of the forum. There are good reasons why people who up- and downvote may  prefer to remain anonymous. As Gerry Myerson says "generators of 6" does not make sense. Also "How can $5_6$ generate $6$" makes no sense. $6$ is not a member of the group. Since $6_6 = 0_6$, the group element corresponding to $6$ is $0_6$, and $5_6+5_6+5_6+5_6+5_6+5_6=0_6$.

Comment: I just want to point out that for someone just starting to learn abstract algebra, notation like $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0_6,1_6,...,5_6\}\;$ can be confusing. In fact, this is suggestive of an equality between two things, but the left side is a group, while the right is merely a set. One might not know in what sense these two things are the same.

Comment: You have covered cosets, Pedro, you just haven't used that word. $\bf Z$ is a group, $6{\bf Z}=\{\,0,\pm6,\pm12,\dots\,\}$ is a subgroup, and $1_6=1+6{\bf Z}=\{\,\dots,-11,-5,1,7,13,\dots\,\}$ is the coset of $6{\bf Z}$ in $\bf Z$ containing 1. Please try to engage with the comments, and let us know if you need further clarifications. Oh, and if you want to know more about "downvoting without explanation", I encourage you to go to the meta site and look for discussion tagged "downvoting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your teacher and/or your text are using the (non-standard) notation $n_m$ to mean $n\pmod m$.

The equation $\mathbb{Z}_6=\{0_6,1_6,...,5_6\}$ is an abuse of notation which is usually interpreted to mean that $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is a group with elements $\{0_6,1_6,...,5_6\}$ and group operation defined by $a_6 \star b_6 = (a+b)_6$. You can check that this is a group. It is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ because its elements are not elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, its elements are in fact subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$. One of those subsets, $0_6$, is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. The others are not, they are called the "*cosets* of $0_6$ in $\mathbb{Z}$". But we don't  need to deal with them here.

**Your question 1**: A set, $S$, of generators for a group, $G$, is a set with the property that every element of $G$ can be written a product of elements of $S$ and their inverses. Thus it looks like you may have a typo in this question since $6$ is not a group.  However, you can show that $6$ generates the subgroup $0_6$ of $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Your question 2**: Observe that $5_6 \star 5_6 = 4_6$ and
$5_6 \star 4_6 = 3_6$ and
$5_6 \star 3_6 = 2_6$ and
$5_6 \star 2_6 = 1_6$ and
$5_6 \star 1_6 = 0_6$.
So every element of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ can be written as a product of the element of the single element set $\{5_6\}$ and thus it generates  $\mathbb{Z}_6$. By an abuse of language we say that the element $5_6$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_6$. Only one other element of  $\mathbb{Z}_6$ generates it.

Comment: Thanks! I have been reading your answer and finally understood it. I was getting so upset about this.